# Laravel - Manage real time interaction

Tags: php, laravel

I search a long time how to do it but I can't find anything.

I'm searching how to manage interaction with user. I don't really know how to explain it and I'm not natif in english so it's hard to explain but somehting who do this :

I have a page with a text input, and all user see this input, one user can enter text in it and I want the other to see the text enter when it's typed.

How manage to "refresh" all user view when it's edit ?

Should I use Ajax ?

Thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thanks, what i need ! Just can't find it